# Is this a bug in Visual C++ 2010, or am I missing something?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Given the following code:

```
#include <vector>

template<class C1, class C2, class Op> 
std::vector<typename Op::result_type> 
f(Op op, const C1& src1, const C2& src2)
{
}

template<class It, class Op> 
std::vector<typename Op::result_type> g(Op op, It begin, It end)
{
}

template<class It1, class It2, class Op>
std::vector<typename Op::result_type> g(Op op, It1 left_begin, It1 left_end, It2 right_begin)
{
    return std::vector<typename Op::result_type>();
}

struct ToS
{
    typedef double result_type;
    double operator() (long , double ) const { return 0.0; }
};

std::vector<double> h(std::vector<long> const& vl, std::vector<double> const& vd)
{
    return g(ToS(), vl.begin(), vl.end(), vd.begin());
}
```

When compiled with Visual C++ 2010 (SP1), I get the following errors:

```
1>VC10Error.cpp(30): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::vector<Op::result_type> g(Op,It1,It1,It2)'
1>          With the following template arguments:
1>          'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<long,std::allocator<long>>
1>          ]
1>          'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<double,std::allocator<double>>
1>          ]
1>          'ToS'
1>VC10Error.cpp(30): error C2780: 'std::vector<Op::result_type> g(Op,It,It)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided
1>          VC10Error.cpp(12) : see declaration of 'g'
```

I don't understand them.  First, of course, the error message basically
sums up as "There's something wrong here, but we won't tell you what'.
And secondly, I don't find anything wrong; nor does g++ (version 4.4.2).
Other interesting symptoms: if you add a `using std::vector;` after the
include, and delete all of the `std::`, it works—I would have
thought that that should have no effect.  And if you delete either the
function `f` (which really isn't used anywhere) or the first version of
function `g`, it also works.

So am I crazy, or is VC10 really not yet production-ready?

EDITED: Just to add: if it is a bug in the compiler, how do I reliably work around it?

Comment: They originally had more descriptive names; I'm required to hide as much as possible the actual code.  The types, etc. were also more complicated in the original; I've tried to simplify as much as possible.

Comment: This *seems* like a compiler bug, moving the second version of `g` so that it is declared first also seems to fix the problem. I suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: James I filed a bug report on this with connect.microsoft.com. Please vote for it if you want to see it fixed in the next release of VC++. Here is the link to it:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678280/vc-2010-sp1-compiler-fails-to-parse-conforming-code#details

Comment: @Dilip I filed a bug report in reaction to the original comments.  I've been informed that it has been fixed (or will be fixed in the next patch level of VC10).

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it appears a bug in the compiler.

In your simplified example, the issue goes away if the two versions of `g()` exchange places, or if `f()` is commented out, or `f()` exchange places with `g<It,Op>(Op, It, It)`.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with g++ compiler. So it's possible that VC++ is not able to parse through it properly (may be a bug in that case). Your code is proper.